# Why npm run dev goes on infinite and circular compiling loop in NextJS 14?

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js

I removed the `node_modules` then I cleaned the cache and updated the dependencies using `npm update`. Everything went well, however when I run `npm run dev` the process take a long time between 10 minutes to 15 minutes with circular compiling :

[image]

I was on NextJS 14.0.3 then I downgraded to 13.4.0 but I still receive the same issue.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "credium-gersthofen-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "predev": "node scripts/babel/backup.js",
    "prebuild": "node scripts/babel/backup.js",
    "precypress-run-component": "node scripts/babel/restore.js",
    "precypress-open-component": "node scripts/babel/restore.js",
    "precypress-run-e2e": "node scripts/babel/restore.js",
    "precypress-open-e2e": "node scripts/babel/restore.js",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-watch": "jest --watch",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint-staged": "npx lint-staged",
    "lint-style": "npx stylelint src/*.css src/**/**/*.css",
    "cypress-open-component": "cypress open --component",
    "cypress-open-e2e": "cypress open --e2e",
    "cypress-run-component": "cypress run --component --headless",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/tailwindcss": "^0.2.0",
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^3.0.0",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^3.0.0",
    "@next/mdx": "^14.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.80.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.2",
    "@tremor/react": "^3.11.0",
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.2.1",
    "@types/mdx": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "20.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "chai-colors": "^1.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "contentlayer": "^0.3.4",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^10.0.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "i18next": "^23.4.3",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
    "i18next-resources-to-backend": "^1.1.4",
    "istanbul-lib-coverage": "^3.2.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.292.0",
    "next": "13.4.0",
    "next-contentlayer": "^0.3.4",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^13.0.3",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "react-to-print": "^2.14.15",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.3",
    "swr": "^2.2.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.0.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "tsconfig-paths-jest": "^0.0.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.7.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.7.0",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.11.0",
    "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript": "^1.0.2",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^1.0.8",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.5.1",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.1.1",
    "cypress": "^13.0.0",
    "cypress-react-selector": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.15",
    "fetch-mock": "^9.11.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-next-dynamic": "^1.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "msw": "^1.2.5",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
    "nyc": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "storybook": "^7.5.1",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^34.0.0",
    "stylelint-prettier": "^4.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

**next.config.ts**

```
const { withContentlayer } = require('next-contentlayer')

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "mdx", "ts", "tsx"],
  eslint: {
    // Warning: This allows production builds to successfully complete even if
    // your project has ESLint errors.
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
}

module.exports = withContentlayer(nextConfig)

// Injected content via Sentry wizard below

const { withSentryConfig } = require("@sentry/nextjs")

module.exports = withSentryConfig(
  module.exports,
  {
    // For all available options, see:
    // https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin#options

    // Suppresses source map uploading logs during build
    silent: true,
    org: "credium",
    project: "gersthofen-app",
  },
  {
    // For all available options, see:
    // https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/

    // Upload a larger set of source maps for prettier stack traces (increases build time)
    widenClientFileUpload: true,

    // Transpiles SDK to be compatible with IE11 (increases bundle size)
    transpileClientSDK: true,

    // Routes browser requests to Sentry through a Next.js rewrite to circumvent ad-blockers (increases server load)
    tunnelRoute: "/monitoring",

    // Hides source maps from generated client bundles
    hideSourceMaps: true,

    // Automatically tree-shake Sentry logger statements to reduce bundle size
    disableLogger: true,
  }
)
```

**.nvmrc:**

```
v20.10.0
```

**.nprmc**

```
package-lock=false
legacy-peer-deps=true
```